# Free space appears on top of the page in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

so i managed to get rid off the space on Firefox and other browsers, but on  Chrome there is a free space on top, which i can't get rid off.

I have set

```
body,html {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

But still it`s there. Can somebody view the page and give some tips how to remove it ? 
The website is [Here](http://funky.lv/)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
html, body { top: 0;}
```

as well as the rest of the css, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chrome's DOM-inspector, you have some text directly after the body tag (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ThOO.jpg). If you go to the DOM-inspector, click on the text and hit <kbd>del</kbd> to delete it, the space will be gone. You'll probably have to remove some of the white space in your template, as Chrome seems to be a little picky.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the css error. Format the code well..

There is the extra "" code after the body opening tag ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encoding of your document to UTF8 without BOM, it can help you to solve your problem.